# Deletable Chips in Material UI Multiple Select

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, event-handling, material-ui

The Material UI documentation includes an example of a [multiple select](https://material-ui.com/components/selects/#multiple-select) where the selected options are rendered with the `Chip` component by using the `renderValue` prop on the `Select`.  The standard behavior for the `Select` component is that clicking on the current value opens the list of options.

I am trying to tweak this so that the `Chip`s show the `X` button, and clicking on the `X` should instantly remove that item from the selections rather than opening the options list.

That seems easy, but I can't get the `onDelete` event of the `Chip` to fire.  Clicking the `X` still just opens the `Select`.

How can I get the `onDelete` event to take priority?  From what I know about event bubbling, it seems like the `Chip` *should* handle the event first.

[Code Sandbox Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-vndvq?file=/demo.tsx)

Code:

```
const MultipleSelectDemo = () => {
  const [personName, setPersonName] = React.useState<string[]>(initialSelected);

  const handleChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<{ value: unknown }>) => {
    setPersonName(event.target.value as string[]);
  };
  
  // this never gets called
  const handleDelete = (e: React.MouseEvent, value: string) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("clicked delete");
    setPersonName((current) => _without(current, value));
  };

  return (
      <div>
        <FormControl>
          <InputLabel id="demo-mutiple-chip-checkbox-label">
            Chip + Check
          </InputLabel>
          <Select
            labelId="demo-mutiple-chip-checkbox-label"
            id="demo-mutiple-chip-checkbox"
            multiple
            value={personName}
            onChange={handleChange}
            onOpen={() => console.log("select opened")}
            IconComponent={KeyboardArrowDownIcon}
            renderValue={(selected) => (
              <div>
                {(selected as string[]).map((value) => (
                  <Chip
                    key={value}
                    label={value}
                    clickable
                    className={classes.chip}
                    onDelete={(e) => handleDelete(e, value)}
                    onClick={() => console.log("clicked chip")}
                  />
                ))}
              </div>
            )}
          >
            {names.map((name) => (
              <MenuItem key={name} value={name}>
                <Checkbox checked={personName.includes(name)} />
                <ListItemText primary={name} />
              </MenuItem>
            ))}
          </Select>
        </FormControl>
      </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The opening of the `Select` is triggered by the [mouse-down event](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.11.0/packages/material-ui/src/Select/SelectInput.js#L374) -- not the click event.

You can get your desired behavior by stopping propagation of the mouse-down event when it occurs on the delete icon of the `Chip`:

```
                  <Chip
                    key={value}
                    label={value}
                    clickable
                    deleteIcon={
                      <CancelIcon
                        onMouseDown={(event) => event.stopPropagation()}
                      />
                    }
                    className={classes.chip}
                    onDelete={(e) => handleDelete(e, value)}
                    onClick={() => console.log("clicked chip")}
                  />
```

[image: Edit Deletable Chip in multi-Select]

Comment: Is there a way to set some text when there are no chips present as a result of renderValue? I would like to display something like "No items present" by itself or as a Chip.

Answer (score 3):

For people who still find answer for this question, MUI has a component does exactly what you want: Autocomplete, you can find it here: https://mui.com/material-ui/react-autocomplete/

Here is the code example from MUI documents: [Code Sandbox Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/1rmkod?file=/demo.tsx)

Comment: You can improve your answer by adding code example with MuiV5 and autocomplete to solve above problem. old accepted answer is done with Mui V4.

Comment: Yes sure, thanks for your feedback, I added code example for this problem

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33109828)

Comment: This was very very helpful, thanks